# ¿Se puede insertar un registro y hacer consultar justo después del insert?

Tags: mysql

Buenas, mi pregunta es tengo una duda, porque tengo un registro que voy a insertar, pero luego inmediatamente que consultarlo, algo así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (rut_alumno,nombre_completo,direccion,telefono,correo,id_estado,id_matricula,id_nivel) 
VALUES ('$rut','$name','$address','$phone','$email',1,$matricula,$curso)";
mysql_query($sql,$con) or die("El error es en sql insert 1: ".mysql_error());

$sql2 = "SELECT rut_alumno FROM alumno WHERE rut_alumno=$rut"; 
$query2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con) or die("el error query 2 es  :".mysql_error()); 
$fila = mysql_fetch_row($query2); 
echo "resultado es :".$fila[0];
```

lo intenté y no devuelve nada de la base de datos, gracias de antemano.

Comment: disculpa, el código es más ilustrativo, solo para dar una idea, pero mi pregunta es la que se debe tomar en cuenta,¿ es posible hacer INSERT después inmediatamente hacer un SELECT?, y si verifiqué y guarda los datos.

Comment: no quiero el código deseado, tampoco lo estoy buscando, solamente quiero saber si mi pregunta es posible, porque no muestra datos.

Comment: Mira, este es el resto del código:  $query2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con) or die("el error query 2 es :".mysql_error());
    $fila = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
    echo "resultado es :".$fila[0];

Comment: si es posible solo luego de hacer el insert debes hacer el select

Comment: es que no me muestra nada, o mi código está mal?

Comment: agrega el codigo ejemplo a tu pregunta, igual veo sospechoso `rut_alumno=$rut` deberia de ser  `rut_alumno='$rut' `

Comment: esp haré ahora :)

Comment: de ambas maneras lo guarda, pero lo dejaré como mencionaste.

Comment: Y no sería más fácil comprobar si tu `insert` fue insertado correctamente, y en su caso lanzas el mensaje `echo "resultado es: $rut";`, te va dar el mismo resultado que tu `select` y optimizaras tu código. Otra cosa en cuenta `mysql*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.`, http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score -1):

Claro que se puede. El SELECT tendría que tener las siguientes condiciones SELECT * FROM ALUMNO ORDER BY PK_ALUMNO DESC LIMIT 1, donde PK_ALUMNO sería un campo INT AUTO_INCREMENT y la consulta tendría que hacerce una vez hecho el INSERT. Saludos.